# Inconsistent accessibility in constructer parameter Type List in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

As mentioned in other similar post , i have made `CurrencyConfiguration currencyConfiguration12` public.  Still i am getting Inconsistent accessiblity error.
 Please have a look

thanks

```
public partial class AddCurrency : Form
    {
      private List<CurrencyDefination> listcur  = new List<CurrencyDefination>();
        public CurrencyConfiguration currencyConfiguration12;
        public AddCurrency()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeResources();
        }

        private void InitializeResources()
        {

            this.currencyConfiguration1 = new ExchangeRateTable.CurrencyConfiguration(listcur);
            // more code
        }
    }
```

In ExchangeRateTable.CurrencyConfiguration

```
public partial class CurrencyConfiguration : UserControl
    {
        List<CurrencyDefination> currencyCombinationList;
        private List<CurrencyDefination> listcur1;

        public CurrencyConfiguration(List<CurrencyDefination> listcur)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.listcur1 = listcur;
        }
        // More code
    }
```

`Error : Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'List<CurrencyDefination>' is less accessible than field 'AddCurrency.listcur`'

Error Occurs in Constructor of `CurrencyConfiguration`

Comment: In what line does the error occur?

Comment: In constructor of `CurrencyConfiguration `

Comment: Check, please, if `CurrencyDefination` is a *public* class? Since `List<CurrencyDefination>` is passed into *public* constructor

Comment: yes Currency Defination is a public Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have to declare `CurrencyDefination` as *public* class:

```
  public class CurrencyDefination { ... }
```

since `List<CurrencyDefination>` is exposed as *public* constructor parameter of *public* class:

```
  // class is public
  public partial class CurrencyConfiguration : UserControl {
    ...
    // constructor is public thus 
    // List<CurrencyDefination> (and CurrencyDefination) must be public
    public CurrencyConfiguration(List<CurrencyDefination> listcur) {
    }
  }
```

please note, that `public CurrencyConfiguration currencyConfiguration12` is declaring a *method* being *public*, not *class*.